# What is the difference between a cyclic function and a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, language-agnostic, functional-programming

I would like a brief description of the difference between cyclic functions and recursive functions with example.

For example, let us assume we have 3 functions A B and C. I know that if function A calls same function its called recursion. What about if A calls B, then B calls C, and then C calls A?

Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 3):

Recursive function is a function that calls itself.

It may call itself directly (A calls A), or indirectly (A calls B, B calls C, C calls A). It's still a recursion.

Answer (score 2):

It is called indirect recursion.

```
void foo(void)
{
    bar();
}

void bar(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

In the C Standard (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.5.2.2p11) "Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly **and indirectly through any chain of other functions**."

Without an exit condition (like in my example), you likely end up in a stack overflow (stack frames are infinitely added at each call until stack is full).

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this difference is referred to as the difference between *direct* and *indirect* recursion. A function that calls itself is clearly recursive, but even a cycle of functions that ends up calling itself is recursive!

We call the former case *direct recursion*, and the latter case *indirect recursion*.

#### Direct Recursion

```
void foo() {
    foo();
}
```

#### Indirect Recursion

```
void foo() {
    bar();
}

void bar() {
    foo();
}
```